# Android - Layout Height not updating

Tags: android

I have a Scrollview inside that i have a LinearLayout. LinearLayout has some views.
For ex:- My LinearLayout height is 100.
After i removed all views from LinearLayout also i get the same height as 100.
How to update the current height. That is 0 when no views is present.

My code:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You'll probably want to post a little bit more of your layout xml code. That one line doesn't really tell us anything

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `android:layout_weight="1"` from you `LinearLayout` if you want it to get 0 height if no views are visible.